# How to create a dataframe from multiple dictionaries?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How can I create a data frame from multiple dictionaries?

Suppose the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

Open = {'Open': np.array([86.34, 84.04, 79.06, 78.46, 75.85, 80.78, 79.66, 80.67, 82.32,80.1 , 77.63, 77.  , 79.15, 76.32, 77.  , 77.11, 77.04, 79.74,79.92, 79.09])}

High = {'High': np.array([86.45, 84.24, 80.29, 79.11, 79.98, 80.98, 80.57, 82.18, 83.25,81.25, 78.28, 79.2 , 79.19, 77.55, 79.  , 77.5 , 81.93, 81.04,82.48, 86.74])}

Low = {'Low': np.array([83.15, 79.07, 75.59, 76.99, 74.78, 77.45, 78.48, 80.11, 80.35, 77.  , 71.96, 76.15, 76.73, 75.83, 76.11, 73.46, 76.55, 78.7 ,77.65, 78.47])}

Close = {'Close': np.array([84.02, 79.17, 77.28, 77.56, 79.24, 79.86, 79.91, 82.03, 81.83,77.63, 76.19, 79.13, 76.85, 76.98, 78.31, 77.49, 81.65, 80.57,77.92, 85.51])}

index = pd.date_range('2021-1-1',periods=20)
```

I'm able to create a dataframe from one dictionary as evidenced by the below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(Open, index = index)
```

However, I'm unable to extend this syntax using a list of dictionaries and get:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([Open, High, Low, Close] index = index)
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (4,4) indices imply (20,4)
```

How can I construct a dataframe from multiple dictionaries where each column is a dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You merge multiple `dict` into one

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Open, **High, **Low, **Close), index = index)
df
             Open   High    Low  Close
2021-01-01  86.34  86.45  83.15  84.02
2021-01-02  84.04  84.24  79.07  79.17
2021-01-03  79.06  80.29  75.59  77.28
2021-01-04  78.46  79.11  76.99  77.56
2021-01-05  75.85  79.98  74.78  79.24
2021-01-06  80.78  80.98  77.45  79.86
2021-01-07  79.66  80.57  78.48  79.91
2021-01-08  80.67  82.18  80.11  82.03
2021-01-09  82.32  83.25  80.35  81.83
2021-01-10  80.10  81.25  77.00  77.63
2021-01-11  77.63  78.28  71.96  76.19
2021-01-12  77.00  79.20  76.15  79.13
2021-01-13  79.15  79.19  76.73  76.85
2021-01-14  76.32  77.55  75.83  76.98
2021-01-15  77.00  79.00  76.11  78.31
2021-01-16  77.11  77.50  73.46  77.49
2021-01-17  77.04  81.93  76.55  81.65
2021-01-18  79.74  81.04  78.70  80.57
2021-01-19  79.92  82.48  77.65  77.92
2021-01-20  79.09  86.74  78.47  85.51
```